# Text' is imported from both Platforms

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-packages, flutter-android, flutter-html

i am working on a flutter project. I am creating an app that could run on both mobile and web simultenously. for platform checking i used kIsWeb constant which is working fine on Web but when i run the app on Mobile (android) then it says that some of widgets are imported for both packages like in this example.

```
Text' is imported from both 'package:universal_html/src/html.dart' and 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart'.
```

i google it and i found a package `universal_html` but when i used this imprt in my project this gave mein the same error.
is there any thing that i am missing from my code ?
if yes. then highlight my mistake and guid me in this regard.

Comment: Assing an alias to at least one of the imports in order to differentiate them like `import 'package:universal_html/src/html.dart' as html`, and if you want to use `Text` from that import use it like `aliasName.ClassName` e.g. `html.Text`.

Comment: @Ante Bule it says me "The element type 'Text' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget"

Comment: You are probably using `Text` from the wrong  import. `package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart` should be used in the widget tree. So the solution for you should be `import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart' as widgets`, and usage e.g. `Container(child: widgets.Text('some text'))`

Comment: let me try this...

Comment: if i use images then should i do the same procedure for images also

Comment: Depends on where the images are. If they are inside of `package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart` file then yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250346/discussion-between-aqeel-mughal-and-ante-bule).

Comment: @anteBule your answer made my day... it worked like a charm...

Answer (score 1):

This happened because you export `Text` in both `universal_html` and `flutter` package, I recommend use prefiex on `universal_html` like this:

```
import 'package:universal_html/src/html.dart' as universal_html;
```

and use it like this for example:

```
final div = universal_html.DivElement();
```